# inscribed in or inscribed on

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

the title is inscribed in the spine or the title is inscribed on the spine?

What is right and where is the difference? And is it right to say: Words were inscribed on the sign?

Answer (score 0):

I would say "inscribed on" for this as the title is on the outside of the book. It's the same as "written on" and "written in". However, you can say "The spine is inscribed (with the title)", which doesn't follow for "written".

You might say "inscribed in" when:

- The inscription is inside something, e.g. "inscribed in the book".
- You are describing something about the words themselves. e.g. "inscribed in red ink" or "inscribed in a circle" (the words form a circle).

"Inscribed on the sign" sounds correct, but it might be more natural to say "written on". It might be assumed that an inscription is hand-made rather than printed.